# How to sort a CSV file alphabetically?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

This is my code that adds the data to the CSV file known as studentScores.csv

```
myfile = open("studentScores.csv", "a+")

newRecord = Score, Name, Gender, FormGroup, Percentage

myfile.write(str(newRecord))

myfile.write("\n")

myfile.close()
```

As a part of my task, I need to alphabetise the data in the CSV, I have searched, and searched for a solution, but I am unable to find a working solution for me. I am pretty new to Python, so the simplest solution will be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to read the entire CSV file into a list, sort it, then write it back into the file. You should also be using the `csv` module.

Comment: *"I am unable to find a working solution for me"* - then write one.

Comment: @deceze There are several columns with several records. How would I get that into a list without it going out of its order? Furthermore, how would I sort it and I am using the `csv` module. It's been imported at the top of my code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm unsure how to, I meant that I has searched on multiple websites with no solution being clear enough for me to implement it.

Comment: Uhm, you've imported it, but you don't seem to be using any of its functions for reading or writing a CSV file...!? I'm also not sure what the issue with several columns would be.

Comment: @deceze Like I said, I'm new to Python, this is a school project. I'm just seeking a little help.

Comment: This isn't a code-writing or tutorial site, it's not here for general guidance. You need to break this problem down into the smallest possible steps, then solve each one.

Comment: It's alright, @Gijs helped me, I doubt it would have taken you guys 20 seconds to come up with a solution. I appreciate that you want me to solve my own problems with this. I understand that's what programming is about, but I have a time limit for this. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

with open('studentScores.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = [line for line in csv.reader(f)]

newRecord = [Score, Name, Gender, FormGroup, Percentage]
data.append(newRecord)

data.sort(key=itemgetter(1))  # 1 being the column number

with open('studentScores.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows(data)
```

First of all, this uses functions from the `csv` module for properly parsing and creating CSV syntax. Secondly, it reads all existing entries into `data`, appends the new record, sorts all records, then dumps them back to the file.

If you're using a header row in your CSV file to add names to columns, look at [`DictReader` and `DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), that would allow you to handle columns by name, not number (e.g. in the sorting step).

Comment: `data.sort(key=itemgetter(1))  # 1 being the column number
IndexError: list index out of range` I have absolutely no idea what this means...

Comment: Probably that one of your rows is empty/has less than 2 items in it. Debug with `print(data)` before sorting and see if all your rows have a `1` index.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that there's a column being created with nothing in it, shown as so: `[]`. I'm struck as to what to do from here, your solution works as so far, I just need to sort that out. I'll keep working on it, thank you for your help.